# GitHub Mirror to Local Machine/Server

Tags: git, github

We use  few projects (downloaded from github) from github. Since these project are mirrored from github as third_party project in cmake, clean build causes all the projects to be download again. We are behind proxy and downloading sometime takes 1-2 hrs (Traffic is contending with FB traffic and we can't control).

I have been thinking of setting up mirror server locally, and all the project download happens from that server. However I don't want to change the path in my local server ( ie *https://github.com/google/grpc.git* should be same as *https://github-local-mirror.com/google/grpc.git* ).

I understand I can configure local git repo and cloned from the local git repo and periodically updating local git repo from github, however path issue is very important.

Is there any way out here to maintain same path as github? Is there anything called local mirror service which allow github project to be mirrored locally ?

*All question I have read so far talked about mirror on github, I want mirroring from github. So Please think before marking as duplicate.*

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way out here to maintain same path as github?

Yes: simply clone them on your mirror using the same path that they have on GitHub.

> Is there anything called local mirror service which allow github project to be mirrored locally ?

No, but it's trivial.  On your mirror machine, you will want to run:

```
git clone --mirror <github-URL>
```

such that each clone winds up available *on* the mirror at `google/path` when it was at *`path`* on GitHub.  Having done that, you can simply run a `git fetch --prune` (or `git remote update --prune`) in each clone.

Given that there is going to be a small, finite list of mirrors you will maintain, you can simply have a (file containing a) list of `path`s on your mirror machine and use a cron job to run the updates, e.g.:

```
*/5 * * * *   for path in $(cat $HOME/mirrors); do (cd $path && git remote update -p); done
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if any existing solution as it may be very generic issue faced by quite a few people. Nonethe less thanks again !

Comment: I have set this up before, at more than one place. The mirroring is the trivial part; the hard part is all the special weirdness that every place has surrounding their own repository setups.

Comment: This service  https://github.com/beefsack/git-mirror seems  to be doing the job, I will try and update.